# Issue with protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I created this script to run the transpiling for e2e.

> "e2e-transpile": "tsc ./projects/**-e2e/src/**/*.ts || exit 0”

.But it says no files are found when running on windows but it works fine on Mac. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it says no files are found when running on windows but it works fine on Mac. Any help would be great.

You are relying on OS specific expansion. Better if you move it into a `tsconfig.json` option e.g. file `tsconfig.e2e.json`

```
{
  include: [
    './projects/-e2e/src'
  ]
}
```

And run it as :

```
"e2e-transpile": "tsc -p tsconfig.e2e.json || exit 0”
```